# How to modify one column and copy one DataTable into another DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a DataTable which has  the currency pair field and other columns  as follows
[image]

I tried the following way to implement this

```
    private void CopyColumns(DataTable source, DataTable dest, params string[] columns)
    {
        foreach (DataRow sourcerow in source.Rows)
        {
            DataRow destRow = dest.NewRow();
            foreach (string colname in columns)
            {
                destRow[colname] = sourcerow[colname];
            }
            dest.Rows.Add(destRow);
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to copy  one DataTable to another using select and Insert query?

Comment: _" using select and Insert query"_ Do you mean `LINQ-To-DataSet`? Your method is very clear and efficient, no need to use LINQ. All the more because LINQ is a _query_- not an _update_-tool.

Comment: looking at your screen shot, what's the rule to convert from the source table to the destination table?

Comment: Just remove currency pair to  a single currency.ie, remove the currency USD and load the data into the second table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void CopyColumns(DataTable source, DataTable dest, params string[] columns)
{
  dest = source.AsEnumerable()
               .Select(row=> {
                   DataRow newRow = dest.NewRow();
                   newRow[columns[0]] = ((string)row[columns[0]])
                                       .Replace("USD","").Trim('/');                      
                   for(int i = 1; i < columns.Length; i++) {
                     newRow[columns[i]] = row[columns[i]];
                   }
                   return newRow;  
                }).CopyToDataTable();
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest moving the inside of the select into its own method.

Comment: @AlexBeisley what do you mean? you mean place the inside stuff into a **separate method**? I just want to write like this for convenience. Don't be afraid of the so-called `side-effect`, that kind of problem may not be good for `LINQ-to-Entity` but for `LINQ-to-Dataset`, I don't think it matters. The nature of `LINQ` is still based on `loop`.

Comment: It's a select, so I know there won't be a real side effect, but I'm meaning it as a matter of clarity. Creating a complex delegate inside a select is rather messy.

Comment: @AlexBeisley of course, but I think it's not messy enough, I would create a separate method when the code is at least 2 times longer than it's now.

Comment: The problem is, you're missing an opportunity to name something based on it's function. This method as it is violates SRP. A select with a lambda is a different matter because it's a simple pattern. If you can simplify the inside to lambdas, it might be a different story. But generally the method of selecting is more important to the class using a select than the implementation of the pattern.

Comment: @AlexBeisley Anyway the purpose of the answer is point out the idea, this is not a real project, **there are many factors** affecting your decision in how to write a snippet of code when you work in a real project. I guess you can leave such a comment on many many answers here in SO. I don't know how to make you understand on this problem. Hope you join in SO and answer many many questions and feel it yourself.